# How I can associated multiple Facebook accounts ti external account (like Hootsuite)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are developing an application (CMS) which gives the user the possibility to link multiple facebook accounts to the account of the application (CMS).

To do this, we use the facebook php SDK and the "getLoginUrl" function, but the aplication detects that I have active Facebook session, automatically redirects to the URL parameter "redirect_uri".

How I can make the login appears always to capture the token and the username of the account you want to link?

Thank you all in advance, if there is anything you do not understand, please let me know.

Edit: Maybe I have not explained well: The tool is focused on comunity manager, who manage multiple accounts of Facebook or twitter.
The CM may publish content through the tool with various accounts of Facebook (or twitter). As in hootsuite, but more humble;)
Never store passwords for users, but their tokens.

Comment: So you want to link a Facebook account that is not yours? That's not possible I think.

Comment: And Hootsuite.com?
If you register in Hootsuite.com you can link several Facebook accounts to your Hootsuite account. Hootsuite not saved your passwords, but your token, I think.

Comment: Hootsuite lets you manage multiple facebook pages etc, but it does not let you connect users to a certain app that you want. Otherwise everyone could use everyone's login to connect to apps or websites.

Comment: The user should not even have _multiple_ Facebook accounts, because that would violate Facebook’s terms (at least if you are talking about personal accounts here). / If you have a logged in user, then give them the ability to _log out_ first, before logging in with another account.

Comment: I don't think so, I have two accounts in Facebook, the personal one and profesional one, and I linked them to my Hootsuite account.
And the case of Community Manager which manage several accountS?

Comment: CBroe, yes, I'm talking about personal accounts.

Comment: Maybe I have not explained well: The tool is focused on comunity manager, who manage multiple accounts of Facebook or twitter.
The CM may publish content through the tool with various accounts of Facebook (or twitter). As in hootsuite, but more humble;)
Never store passwords for users, but their tokens.

Comment: In a few words, it is to show the Facebook login popup always, regardless if the user is logged into Facebook or not.
Nobody?

Comment: After much research and debug (Google Developer tools, I love you:) ), I already know how to do Hootsuite's guys it; just logout the active Facebook user and therefore kill the session, enabling the login dialog pops. 
Very traditional but effective, :)

Comment: As if that wasn’t what I already recommended six hours earlier …

Comment: Ups, CBroe, it's true. Sorry.